# Double listing of Shvatim on Cohen clothing

Tags: shevatim-12-tribes, tetzaveh, bigdei-kehunah

We learn (Tetzaveh 28:9) that the names of the 12 Shvatim go on the Shoham stones at the straps of the Ephod. (28:12). But also, perhaps more famously, the Cohen (Gadol?) also had them on the Choshen/Urim v’Tumim. (28:21).

If so, the Cohan(im) at some point had all the Shvatim’s names somewhere on their clothing twice!

Anyone know who talks about why the duplication?

Comment: I think I saw the kli yakar address this

Answer (score 2):

[Rabbi Immanuel Bernstein](https://outorah.org/p/82553) says in an article about the Miluim stones that the two appearances of the names relate to their significance as part of the nation (on the Shoham stones) and to their individual significance (on the Choshen):

> It is worthwhile noting, in this regard, that the names of the tribes
> of Israel are engraved on two sets of stones worn by the Kohen Gadol;
> for in addition to the twelve Miluim Stones, there are also two Shoham
> Stones on the shoulders of the Ephod, which have the names of six
> tribes engraved on each stone. These two engravings represent the two
> capacities in which the twelve tribes of Israel exist:
>
> ·     On the one hand, they are all part of the nation of Israel. In
> this regard, their names are all listed together on the two identical
> Shoham stones.
>
> ·     At the same time, each tribe has its individual character and
> mission within the Jewish people. This is reflected by the twelve
> Miluim stones, all of different colors, which are then embedded within
> the framework of the Choshen.